# Specify path for generated classes in Annotation Processor

Tags: java, android, annotations, velocity, annotation-processing

I am creating an Android application. I using AbstractProcessor to generate my own classes from Annotated classes and Velocity templates.

This is the method that generates source file.

```
  private void createSourceFile(String className, String packageName, 
                  VelocityContext context, Template template) throws IOException {

     final JavaFileObject javaFileObject = 
         processingEnv.getFiler().createSourceFile(packageName + "." + className);

     processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "creating file: " + javaFileObject.toUri());
     final Writer writer = javaFileObject.openWriter();
     if (DEBUGGING) {
        processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "applying velocity template: " + template.getName());
     }
     template.merge(context, writer);
     writer.close();
  }
```

My question is

### Can I specify a directory for generated classes?

Right now they are in ***build/source/apt*** folder and I want to generate them in another source folder to make them visible during development. Right now I use `DexFile` to find this classes but in new AndroidStudio with InstanseRun or when I use Kotlin or any other random situation DexFile stop to gather my generated classes.

Comment: did you find a solution to your question?